# How to make black background in cv2.putText with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a project of `opencv` where on the frame I am displaying some text using `cv2.putText()`. Currently it looks like below:

[image]

As you can see on the top left corner, the text is present but its not clearly visible. Is it possible to make background black so that the text will then appear good. Something like below image:

[image]

Even if the black background covers till right side of the frame, that is also fine. Below is the code I am using for putting text on frame:

```
cv2.putText(frame, "Data: N/A", (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.putText(frame, "Room: C1", (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

Is there any prebuilt method/library available in opencv which can do this. Can anyone please suggest a good way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no prebuilt method but a simple appraoch is to use [`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle) + [`cv2.putText`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext). All you need to do is to draw the black rectangle on the image followed by placing the text. You can adjust the `x,y,w,h` parameters depending on how large/small you want the rectangle. Here's an example:

Input image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, define rectangle bounds
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
x,y,w,h = 0,0,175,75

# Draw black background rectangle
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, x), (x + w, y + h), (0,0,0), -1)

# Add text
cv2.putText(image, "THICC flower", (x + int(w/10),y + int(h/2)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255,255,255), 2)

# Display
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you do not know if the text will run outside the black rectangle or if the text will be too small for the black rectangle, unless you calculate the size that the text will need from the font metrics.

Answer (score 32):

Use this function:

```
import cv2

def draw_text(img, text,
          font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
          pos=(0, 0),
          font_scale=3,
          font_thickness=2,
          text_color=(0, 255, 0),
          text_color_bg=(0, 0, 0)
          ):

    x, y = pos
    text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_scale, font_thickness)
    text_w, text_h = text_size
    cv2.rectangle(img, pos, (x + text_w, y + text_h), text_color_bg, -1)
    cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y + text_h + font_scale - 1), font, font_scale, text_color, font_thickness)

    return text_size
```

Then you can invoke the function like this:

```
image = 127 * np.ones((100, 200, 3), dtype="uint8")
pos = (10, 10)
w, h = draw_text(image, "hello", pos=(10, 10))
draw_text(image, "world", font_scale=4, pos=(10, 20 + h), text_color_bg=(255, 0, 0))
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: draw text with background in OpenCV]

note that by default it paints a black background, but you can use a different color if you want.

Comment: This seems to be a better solution than the selected one!

Comment: Nice solution, but got a type error in this line: cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y + text_h + font_scale - 1), font, font_scale, text_color, font_thickness). I had to convert the expression "y + text_h + font_scale - 1" to int. This line should read then: cv2.putText(img, text, (x, int(y + text_h + font_scale - 1)), font, font_scale, text_color, font_thickness)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do that in Python OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Create an image of your desired background color that is the same size as the input
- Draw your text on the background image
- Get the bounding rectangle for the text region
- Copy the text region from the background color image to a copy of the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("zelda1.jpg")

# create same size image of background color
bg_color = (0,0,0)
bg = np.full((img.shape), bg_color, dtype=np.uint8)

# draw text on bg
text_color = (0,0,255)
cv2.putText(bg, "Data: N/A", (5,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.75, text_color, 1)

# get bounding box
# use channel corresponding to color so that text is white on black background
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(bg[:,:,2])
print(x,y,w,h)

# copy bounding box region from bg to img
result = img.copy()
result[y:y+h, x:x+w] = bg[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("zelda1_background_text.jpg", bg)
cv2.imwrite("zelda1_text.jpg", result)

# display results
cv2.imshow("TEXT", bg)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Text on background color image:

[image]

Text on input image:

[image]

P.S. You can adjust the bounding rectangle (x,y,w,h) values to add some padding if you want when you do the crop.

Answer (score 3):

```
import cv2 \
import numpy as np

#### Load image, define rectangle bounds
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Bharath\Downloads\test.jpg')

#### overlay space
x,y,w,h = 40,30,300,60


#### alpha, the 4th channel of the image
alpha = 0.3

overlay = image.copy()
output = image.copy()


##### corner
cv2.rectangle(overlay, (x, x), (x + w, y + h), (0,0,0), -1)

##### putText
cv2.putText(overlay, "HELLO WORLD..!", (x + int(w/10),y + int(h/1.5)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255,255,255), 2)

#### apply the overlay
cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha,0, output)


##### Display
cv2.imshow("Output", output)\
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`

*input*
[image]

*output*[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [answer by @estebanuri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65146731/23466407), I have created a slightly over-engineered [public gist](https://gist.github.com/thkodin/92ba80105cb6c15f7dbd203979966c25#file-opencv_text_drawer-py) that should be highly general. The code is attached below (exactly the same as in the gist, except that it's formatted with `black` set to line-length 79):

```py
# opencv_text_drawer.py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def drawText(
    img: type[np.ndarray],
    text: str,
    img_bottom_left_origin: bool = False,
    text_position: int | tuple[int, int] | str = "top_left",
    text_color: tuple[int, int, int] = (0, 0, 255),
    text_font: int = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
    text_font_scale: float = 1.0,
    text_font_thickness: int = 1,
    text_line_type: int = cv2.LINE_AA,
    add_textbg: bool = True,
    textbg_symmetric_baseline_adjustment: bool = True,
    textbg_in_text_bounds: bool = False,
    textbg_color: tuple[int, int, int] = (0, 0, 0),
    textbg_thickness: int = cv2.FILLED,
    textbg_line_type: int = cv2.LINE_AA,
    textbg_padding: (
        int
        | float
        | tuple[int, int]
        | tuple[float, float]
        | tuple[int, int, int, int]
        | tuple[float, float, float, float]
    ) = 0,
):
    """
    Draw text on an image.

    Parameters
    ----------
    img : type[np.ndarray]
        The image to draw the text on.
    text : str
        The text to draw.
    img_bottom_left_origin : bool, optional
        Whether to assume image has a bottom-left origin, by default False. If
        True, treats the `text_position` as relative to bottom-left instead of
        the usual top-left. Therefore, `text_position="top_left"` is equivalent
        to `text_position="bottom_left"`. Only kept as a working placeholder
        for `bottomLeftOrigin` in OpenCV's `putText()` function.
    text_position : int | tuple[int, int] | str, optional
        The bottom-left corner coordinates for the text box, by default
        "top_left". If an int, x = y = text_pos. If a tuple, it should be (x,
        y) where x and y are the left and bottom coordinates respectively. If a
        string, it should be one of: "top_left", "top_right", "bottom_left",
        "bottom_right", or "center". If the text box goes out of image bounds,
        its position (and nothing else) will be adjusted within the image
        bounds if possible, otherwise an error will be thrown.
    text_color : tuple[int, int, int], optional
        The color of the text in BGR order, by default (0, 0, 255), i.e., red.
    text_font : int, optional
        The font to use, by default cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN (integer code 1).
    text_font_scale : float, optional
        The font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific base
        size, by default 1.
    text_font_thickness : int, optional
        The thickness of the text in pixels, by default 1.
    text_line_type : int, optional
        The line type, by default cv2.LINE_AA (integer code 16).
    add_textbg : bool, optional
        Whether to add a background to the text, by default True.
    textbg_symmetric_baseline_adjustment : bool, optional
        Whether to adjust the text background box symmetrically by the baseline
        amount in the corresponding dimension, by default True. If True, when
        adjusting the original text box for baseline amounts in the horizontal
        and vertical dimensions, the text background box will be adjusted
        symmetrically by the baseline amount in both directions (i.e., left +
        right horizontally, and top + bottom vertically), otherwise the text
        background box will be adjusted non-symmetrically (i.e., only along the
        left horizontally, and bottom vertically) by the baseline amount. The
        baseline amount is the amount by which the bottom edge of the text box
        is pushed down to ensure descending characters like 'g' and 'y' are
        visible. This is only relevant if `add_textbg` is True.
    textbg_in_text_bounds : bool, optional
        Whether to adjust the text background box position to fit within the
        image bounds, by default False. If True, the text background box will
        be used instead of the text box to check for out-of-bounds conditions,
        and the position of the text box will be adjusted to fit within the
        image bounds if possible, otherwise an error will be thrown. Only
        relevant if `add_textbg` is True.
    textbg_color : tuple[int, int, int], optional
        The color of the text background in BGR order, by default (0, 0, 0),
        i.e., black. Only relevant if `add_textbg` is True.
    textbg_padding : int | float | tuple[int, int] | tuple[float, float] |
    tuple[int, int, int, int] | tuple[float, float, float, float], optional
        The padding of the text background, by default 0. Only relevant if
        `add_textbg` is True. Based on the type of the passed value, the
        padding will be interpreted as follows:

        - If an int, the padding is equal on all sides in pixels.
        - If a float, the padding is proportional to the minimum of text box
          dimensions.
        - If a 2-tuple, the first element is the equal horizontal padding in
          both left/right directions, and the second element is equal vertical
          padding in both top/bottom directions. If both elements are ints, the
          padding is in pixels, else if they are floats, the padding in each
          dimension is propotional to the text box size in that dimension.
        - If a 4-tuple, the first element is the left edge padding, the second
          is the top edge padding, the third is the right edge padding, and the
          fourth is the bottom edge padding. If the elements are ints, the
          padding is in pixels, else if they are floats, the padding is
          proportional to the corresponding text box edge.

    Sources
    -------
    - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65146731
    - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73056754
    """
    # Get image size.
    img_height, img_width = img.shape[:2]

    # Get the size of the text box given the text drawing settings. Also get
    # the y-baseline, so we can ensure descending characters ike 'g' and 'y'
    # are visible.

    text_size, bottom_baseline = cv2.getTextSize(
        text, text_font, text_font_scale, text_font_thickness
    )
    left_baseline = 0  # this doesn't exist for typical strings

    # Get text box size.
    text_width, text_height = text_size

    # Figure out the position for the bottom-left corner of the text box.
    # Anything related to the text box position we want to get with respect to
    # the text size we got from the cv2.getTextSize() function without any
    # modification. All later adjustments assume this is true.

    if isinstance(text_position, int):
        # Set the bottom-left corner to the same coordinate in both dimensions
        text_left = text_position
        text_bottom = text_position
    elif isinstance(text_position, tuple):
        # Unpack position tuple asuuming order (x, y) to get the bottom-left
        # corner coordinates of the text box.
        text_left, text_bottom = text_position
    elif isinstance(text_position, str):
        # Set initial text positions. We'll fit them in the respective position
        # later.
        if text_position == "top_left":
            # Text box bottom left coordinates so that left and top edges align
            # with corresponding edges of image, need to push it "down".
            text_left, text_bottom = (0, text_height)
        elif text_position == "top_right":
            # Text box bottom left coordinates so that right and top edges
            # align with the corresponding edges of image, need to pull it
            # "left" AND push it "down".
            text_left, text_bottom = (img_width - text_width, text_height)
        elif text_position == "bottom_left":
            # Text box bottom left coordinates so that left and bottom edges
            # align with the image's, no pull/push needed.
            text_left, text_bottom = (0, img_height)
        elif text_position == "bottom_right":
            # Text box bottom left coordinates so that right and bottom edges
            # align with the corresponding edges of image, need to pull it
            # "left".
            text_left, text_bottom = (img_width - text_width, img_height)
        elif text_position == "center":
            # Text box bottom left coordinates so so that its center aligns
            # with image center, initially put it to image center, then pull it
            # "left" AND push it "down" by half the text box sizes.
            text_left, text_bottom = (
                (img_width - text_width) // 2,
                (img_height + text_height) // 2,
            )
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Expected `text_position` keyword argument to be one of:"
                " 'top_left', 'top_right', 'bottom_left', 'bottom_right', or"
                " 'center'. Got {} instead.".format(text_position)
            )
    else:
        raise TypeError(
            "Expected `text_position` keyword argument to be an int, tuple, or"
            " string. Got {} instead.".format(type(text_position))
        )

    if img_bottom_left_origin:
        text_bottom = (
            img_height - text_bottom
        )  # get the text bottom relative to the bottom edge of the image

    # Create a new text box, this one with the baseline adjustments so that
    # characters exceeding baselines are not cutoff, e.g., in vertical
    # dimension, characters like 'g' and 'y'. Typically, the horizontal
    # dimension has no such issue, but we'll adjust it as well for the sake of
    # completeness assuming left_baseline is 0.

    text_left_baseline_adjusted = (
        text_left - left_baseline
    )  # pull left edge further left
    text_bottom_baseline_adjusted = (
        text_bottom + bottom_baseline
    )  # push bottom edge down

    # Update height and width by double the baseline amount, so that both top
    # and bottom, and left and right edges are expanded by the same
    # corresponding baseline amount (symmetric edge expansion). OR, just update
    # the height and width by the baseline amount, expanding only the left and
    # bottom edges with the corresponding baseline amount (non-symmetric edge
    # expansion). To see how, consider the baseline adjusted bottom edge to be
    # y_b' = y_b + y_baseline, the original being y_b. Similarly, consider that
    # the height of the baseline adjusted text box is h' = h + y_baseline, the
    # original being h. Then, y_top = y_b - h == y_top' = y_b' - h'. In this
    # formulation, the top edge doesn't move! However, if we were to double the
    # baseline amount when computing h' = h + 2 * y_baseline, then y_top = y_b
    # - h != y_top' = y_b' - h' = y_b - 2 * y_baseline, therefore moving the
    # top edge by the same amount as the bottom edge. Similar logic can be
    # applied to the left baseline (if it exists).
    if textbg_symmetric_baseline_adjustment:
        text_width_baseline_adjusted = text_width + 2 * left_baseline
        text_height_baseline_adjusted = text_height + 2 * bottom_baseline
    else:
        text_width_baseline_adjusted = text_width + left_baseline
        text_height_baseline_adjusted = text_height + bottom_baseline

    if add_textbg:
        try:
            if any(x < 0 for x in textbg_padding):
                raise ValueError("Padding must be non-negative.")
        except TypeError:
            if textbg_padding < 0:
                raise ValueError("Padding must be non-negative.")

        # What sort of padding did the user provide? Whatever we had, we need
        # to convert it to a 4-tuple appropriately.

        if isinstance(textbg_padding, int):
            # Pad equally on all sides by this many pixels.
            textbg_pad_ltrb = (
                textbg_padding,
                textbg_padding,
                textbg_padding,
                textbg_padding,
            )
        elif isinstance(textbg_padding, float):
            # Pad equally on all sides propotionally to the minimum of the text
            # box width and height.
            textbg_padding = int(
                textbg_padding
                * min(
                    text_width_baseline_adjusted, text_height_baseline_adjusted
                )
            )
            textbg_pad_ltrb = (
                textbg_padding,
                textbg_padding,
                textbg_padding,
                textbg_padding,
            )
        elif isinstance(textbg_padding, tuple):
            # We have different pad amounts.
            if len(textbg_padding) == 2:
                # Pad amounts are separate for horizontal and vertical
                # dimensions.
                if all(isinstance(x, float) for x in textbg_padding):
                    # Pad amounts are proportional to the text box size along
                    # each dimension.
                    textbg_pad_w = int(
                        textbg_padding[0] * text_width_baseline_adjusted
                    )
                    textbg_pad_h = int(
                        textbg_padding[1] * text_height_baseline_adjusted
                    )
                elif all(isinstance(x, int) for x in textbg_padding):
                    # Pad amounts are exact (pixel units) along each dimension.
                    textbg_pad_w = textbg_padding[0]
                    textbg_pad_h = textbg_padding[1]
                else:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "Expected background padding to be either all ints or"
                        " all floats. Got a mix of {} instead.".format(
                            ", ".join([str(type(x)) for x in textbg_padding])
                        )
                    )
                textbg_pad_ltrb = (
                    textbg_pad_w,
                    textbg_pad_h,
                    textbg_pad_w,
                    textbg_pad_h,
                )
            elif len(textbg_padding) == 4:
                # Pad amounts are separate for each side.
                if all(isinstance(x, float) for x in textbg_padding):
                    # Pad amounts are proportional to the sides.
                    textbg_pad_left = int(
                        textbg_padding[0] * text_width_baseline_adjusted
                    )
                    textbg_pad_top = int(
                        textbg_padding[1] * text_height_baseline_adjusted
                    )
                    textbg_pad_right = int(
                        textbg_padding[2] * text_width_baseline_adjusted
                    )
                    textbg_pad_bottom = int(
                        textbg_padding[3] * text_height_baseline_adjusted
                    )
                elif all(isinstance(x, int) for x in textbg_padding):
                    # Pad amounts are exact (pixel units) along the sides.
                    textbg_pad_left = textbg_padding[0]
                    textbg_pad_top = textbg_padding[1]
                    textbg_pad_right = textbg_padding[2]
                    textbg_pad_bottom = textbg_padding[3]
                else:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "Expected background padding to be either all ints or"
                        " all floats. Got a mix of {} instead.".format(
                            ", ".join([str(type(x)) for x in textbg_padding])
                        )
                    )
                textbg_pad_ltrb = (
                    textbg_pad_left,
                    textbg_pad_top,
                    textbg_pad_right,
                    textbg_pad_bottom,
                )
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Tuples are supported for background padding, but must be"
                    " either a 2-tuple or 4-tuple. Got {}-tuple instead."
                    .format(len(textbg_padding))
                )
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                "Expected background padding to be an int, float, or tuple of"
                " ints and floats. Got {} instead.".format(
                    str(type(textbg_padding))
                )
            )

        # Add the background box.
        textbg_left = text_left_baseline_adjusted - textbg_pad_ltrb[0]
        textbg_bottom = text_bottom_baseline_adjusted + textbg_pad_ltrb[1]
        textbg_width = (
            text_width_baseline_adjusted
            + textbg_pad_ltrb[0]
            + textbg_pad_ltrb[2]
        )
        textbg_height = (
            text_height_baseline_adjusted
            + textbg_pad_ltrb[1]
            + textbg_pad_ltrb[3]
        )

        if textbg_in_text_bounds:
            # Update the baseline-adjusted textbox to reflect the padding.
            text_left_baseline_adjusted = textbg_left
            text_bottom_baseline_adjusted = textbg_bottom
            text_width_baseline_adjusted = textbg_width
            text_height_baseline_adjusted = textbg_height

    # First check if text box fits in the image bounds. If not, raise an error
    # since we cannot fix this without modifying the text content. We only want
    # to perform positional adjustments if ncecessary.
    if (
        text_width_baseline_adjusted > img_width
        or text_height_baseline_adjusted > img_height
    ):
        err_msg = (
            "Text box cannot be drawn on the image as baseline-adjustments"
            " exceed the image bounds:\n"
            if not textbg_in_text_bounds
            else (
                "Text background box cannot be drawn on the image as it"
                " exceeds image bounds:\n"
            )
        )
        err_msg += (
            ""
            if text_width_baseline_adjusted < img_width
            else (
                f"  - Width ({text_width_baseline_adjusted}) exceeds image"
                f" width ({img_width}).\n"
            )
        )
        err_msg += (
            ""
            if text_height_baseline_adjusted < img_height
            else (
                f"  - Height ({text_height_baseline_adjusted}) exceeds image"
                f" height ({img_height}).\n"
            )
        )
        err_msg += (
            "Please adjust the text box contents (e.g., font, font size,"
            " thickness, etc.) to fit it.\n"
            if not textbg_in_text_bounds
            else (
                "Please consider:\n  o Not using the background in bound"
                " calculation by setting `textbg_in_text_bounds` to False\n  o"
                " Adjust text box contents (e.g., font, font size, thickness,"
                " etc.) to fit it\n  o Adjust the padding (if applied)\n"
            )
        )
        raise ValueError(err_msg)

    # Fixing the out-of-bound text cases. We will consider the
    # baseline-adjusted text box to make the check, and update the actual text
    # box if needed.
    dx = 0
    dy = 0

    if text_left_baseline_adjusted < 0:
        # Left edge of baseline-adjusted text box is to the left of image's
        # left edge. Automatically incorporates the subset case where both the
        # left AND right edges of the text box are to the left of the image's
        # left edge.
        dx = text_left_baseline_adjusted
    elif (
        text_left_baseline_adjusted + text_width_baseline_adjusted > img_width
    ):
        # Right edge of baseline-adjusted text box is to the right of image's
        # right edge. Automatically incorporates the subset case where both the
        # left AND right edges of the text box are to the right of the image's
        # right edge.
        dx = (
            text_left_baseline_adjusted
            + text_width_baseline_adjusted
            - img_width
        )

    if text_bottom_baseline_adjusted > img_height:
        # Bottom edge of baseline-adjusted text box is below the image's bottom
        # edge. Automatically incorporates the subset case where both the top
        # AND bottom edges of the text box are below the image's bottom edge.
        dy = text_bottom_baseline_adjusted - img_height
    elif text_bottom_baseline_adjusted - text_height_baseline_adjusted < 0:
        # Top edge of baseline-adjusted text box is above image's top edge.
        # Automatically incorporates the subset case where both the top AND
        # bottom edges of the text box are above the image's top edge.
        dy = text_bottom_baseline_adjusted - text_height_baseline_adjusted

    # Align the baseline-adjusted text box edges with the image edges.
    text_left_baseline_adjusted -= dx
    text_bottom_baseline_adjusted -= dy

    # Update the original text box's edges to reflect the change.
    text_left -= dx
    text_bottom -= dy

    if add_textbg:
        # Update the background box's edges to reflect the change.
        textbg_left -= dx
        textbg_bottom -= dy

        textbg_topleft = (textbg_left, textbg_bottom - textbg_height)
        textbg_bottomright = (textbg_left + textbg_width, textbg_bottom)

        # Draw a filled rectangle to serve as the text background.
        cv2.rectangle(
            img,
            textbg_topleft,
            textbg_bottomright,
            textbg_color,
            thickness=textbg_thickness,
            lineType=textbg_line_type,
        )

    # Draw the text on the image.
    cv2.putText(
        img,
        text,
        (text_left, text_bottom),
        text_font,
        text_font_scale,
        text_color,
        thickness=text_font_thickness,
        lineType=text_line_type,
    )

    return img


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a black image.
    img = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Draw text on the image.
    img = drawText(
        img,
        "Hello, World!",
        img_bottom_left_origin=False,
        text_position="center",
        text_color=(0, 255, 255),
        text_font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
        text_font_scale=1.0,
        text_font_thickness=1,
        text_line_type=cv2.LINE_AA,
        add_textbg=True,
        textbg_symmetric_baseline_adjustment=True,
        textbg_in_text_bounds=True,
        textbg_color=(255, 0, 0),
        textbg_thickness=cv2.FILLED,
        textbg_line_type=cv2.LINE_AA,
        textbg_padding=15,
    )

    # Show the image.
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> The script has been tested in a virtual environment created with mamba
> using `python==3.10`, `opencv-python==4.9.0.80`, and `numpy==1.26.4`
> for quite a few test cases, but there are probably a few I have
> missed; beware that you might encounter the occasional case where it
> fails to work as intended.

## Changes/Additions

---

The function `drawText()` in the script expands on the aforementioned answer's `draw_text()` function with the following:

1. Adjusts the background box for characters descending beyond the text baseline. This is done by pushing the bottom edge of the background box downwards by the second parameter `baseLine` returned by [`cv2.getTextSize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga3d2abfcb995fd2db908c8288199dba82) (which was discarded in the aforementioned answer). Additionally, a symmetric variant of this adjustment is provided in the form of a toggleable option `textbg_symmetric_baseline_adjustment`, which expands both the top AND bottom edges by `baseLine`.
2. Supports equal, dimension-wise, and side-wise padding for the background box in both pixel and proportional (to background box) units, based on the type of data provided to the relevant parameter `textbg_padding`.
3. Allows using multiple types for text position argument `text_position`, i.e., *int* (`x = y = text_position`), *tuple* (`x = text_position[0]`, `y = text_position[1]`), or *str* (`"top_left"`, `"top_right"`, `"bottom_left"`, `"bottom_right"`, and `"center"`). The string options are added as a quick way of setting up (subjectively) common text positions in images. This argument is additionally assumed to strictly represent the bottom-left coordinate of the text box, which is aligned with `cv2.putText()`'s implementation of the equivalent `org` parameter.
4. Allows varying the line types for both the text and background box.
5. Checks that the text to be rendered fits within the image bounds, with an additional option to consider the background box instead (which, by definition, encompasses the text box, regardless of if it is padded or not). If possible (i.e., text box / background box dimensions DO NOT EXCEED image dimensions), they are adjusted to fit within the image bounds with only positional variations, otherwise an error is thrown.
6. While the opposite of what the question asks, allows disabling the background box, which still allows the benefit of baseline adjustment given in Point 1.
7. [UNSURE IF CORRECT] Per my interpretation of how `cv2.putText()`'s keyword argument `bottomLeftOrigin` is supposed to work, allows considering text position from the bottom-left of the image instead of the usual top-left via the boolean parameter `img_bottom_left_origin`.

## Some Results

---

1. [With Symmetric Baseline Adjust + No Padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL8sf.png)
2. [With Symmetric Baseline Adjust + Variable Padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKKrZ.png)
3. [Without Symmetric Baseline Adjust + Variable Padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0atU9.png)
4. [With Symmetric Baseline Adjust + Variable Padding + Bottom Left Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hryUQ.png)

Produced with [this](https://gist.github.com/thkodin/92ba80105cb6c15f7dbd203979966c25#file-other_main_configuration-py) `main()` configuration.

## Notes

---

- The function `drawText()` contains a variable `left_baseline`, which is set to 0 and then never changed. It can also not be provided as a parameter to the function, as I cannot think of a case where this will be anything other than zero. However, I have kept it for the sake of completeness.
- I would have commented the gist link on the original answer, but this is my first post. I hope that is acceptable.